# merge 2 files - column alternatively from file1 and file2

Tags: awk, sed, excel-2007

f1.txt

```
A, 77, 1, 2.0,  !P ,  F, - ,     
B,   77 , 4, 5, P,  P, - ,     
C, 88, 6,  7,   F,   P, -,
```

f2.txt

```
A, 77, 1, 2, P, F,  P,    
B, 77, 4, 5, F, P,  P,    
C, 88, 6, 7, F, P,  P,    
D, 99, 8, 9, P, P,  F,
```

desired output

```
A, 77, 1, 2, P, not P(*), F, F, P, -,    
B, 77, 4, 5, F, P(*), P, P, P, -,    
C, 88, 6, 7, F, F, P, P, F, -,    
D, 99, 8, 9, P, -, P, -, P, -,
```

Basically, matching the 4 columns in two files then merging alternative column from each file: matching 4 columns, then `f2_column5` then `f1_column5`, if different then add `(*)` (if not available then `"-"`)

1. number of column > 1000, # column of `f1.txt` and # column of `f2.txt` not the same
2. the number of row can > 1000 and not the same in `f1.txt` and `f2.txt`
3. (if possible, can the code be extended for more than 2 file input (f1,f2); for example, f3.txt which is

f3.txt :     B,   77 , 4, 5, P,  P, - ,
and the desired output (for 3 input files - f1.txt, f2.txt, f3.txt)

desired output

```
A, 77, 1, 2, P, not P(*), -, -, F, F, P, -, -,    
B, 77, 4, 5, F, P(*),  P(*), P, P, P, P, -, -,    
C, 88, 6, 7, F, F, -,        P, P, -, F, -, -,   
D, 99, 8, 9, P, -, -,        P, -, -, P, -, -,

             |               |        |
            f2.5th          f2.6th   f2.7th
```

=======================================================================================

If the number of column is less than 10, I can use the following

```
awk 'FNR==NR {a[NR]=$1;
b[NR]=$2;
c[NR]=$3;
d[NR]=$4;
e[NR]=$5;
f[NR]=$6;
g[NR]=$7;
next}
{print $1,$2,$3,$4,$5,
( e[FNR]!="" ? e[FNR] : "-" ),
$6,
( f[FNR]!="" ? f[FNR] : "-" ),
$7,
( g[FNR]!="" ? g[FNR] : "-" ) }' f1.txt f2.txt
```

but this I assume the 4 columns of `f1.txt` and `f2.txt`, not what I want; I want to see if it is a match.  I don't know how to do it with large number of column as well the checking to have (*).

Comment: If there are two spaces between the characters, does that count as a column being not available? Is there exactly one space between each column?

Comment: the number of spaces are not fixed, and space can be field separator or the file can have "," as field separator (however, there is still space, i.e, need to remove leading spaces as well as)  ... Also, there is multiple files (like f1.txt), can the code be worked for multi files ?   Another thing I would like to ask if the number is floating number such as 8.2 then how to convert string of "8.2" to number "8.2"  (i know to use int to do string convert to integer but I did not see any for string to floating number and vice versa).   Thanks.

Comment: If you have additional details to add to your question, you should edit it to make it as clear as possible exactly what you're trying to do.

Comment: I did update the question in detail (input files and desired outputs).  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that your question is at risk of being too broad, but hopefully this serves as a starting point. Currently, the output is not quite correct but it shouldn't be too difficult to tweak the code to meet your needs.

For a script of this length, I think that it is better to write an awk script. The code can be saved to a file and run using `awk -f script.awk f1 f2`:

```
BEGIN { FS = "[[:space:]]*,[[:space:]]*" }
NR == FNR {
    k = $1 SUBSEP int($2) SUBSEP int($3) SUBSEP int($4)
    seen[k]=NF
    for (i=5; i<=NF; ++i) { 
        a[k,i] = $i 
    }
    next
}
{
    k = $1 SUBSEP int($2) SUBSEP int($3) SUBSEP int($4)
    seen[k]=seen[k]>NF?seen[k]:NF
    for (i=5; i<=NF; ++i) { 
        b[k,i] = $i
    }
}
END {
    for (i in seen) {
        n = split(i, c, SUBSEP)
        for (j=1; j<=n; ++j)
            printf "%s, ", c[j]
        for (k=5; k<seen[i]; ++k)
            printf "%s, %s,%s", b[i,k], a[i,k], (k<seen[i]-1?OFS:ORS)            
    }
}
```

Explanation:

- Set the Field Separator to a comma, surrounded by any number of white space characters
- When `NR==FNR` (in the first file):

  - Set the array key `k` to the string made up of the first four fields separated by the special variable `SUBSEP`. Use `int()` to cast the numbers to their integer value
  - The array `seen` keeps a track of the keys that have been so far. The value in the array is set to the number of fields, which is used in the loop later
  - Loop through all of the fields starting from 5 and set the value of the field in the array `a`
  - Skip to the `next` record, ignoring any of the rest of the instructions
- In the second file:

  - Set the key `k` again in the same way
  - If the second file has a greater number of fields for this key, update the value in `seen` (I'm not sure if each line in the file has the same number of keys?)
  - Save each field in the file into the array `b`
- Once all records have been processed:

  - Loop through the keys in `seen`
  - Split the keys on the delimiter `SUBSEP` which we used earlier
  - `split` returns the number of elements in the array `c`
  - Loop through each element and print the value
  - Loop from 5 to the maximum number of fields, printing the alternate values from `a` and `b`

Things that need doing:

- check whether `b[i,k]` and `a[i,k]` are different, so the `(*)` can be added
- replace `!` with `not`
  Both these things are just a case of adding extra logic to the `END` block.

Comment: Thanks.  Could you explain it, please ?

Comment: Sure, hopefully that helps.

Comment: it works thanks.  However, I dont know how to do the next things (adding (*) if b[i,k] and a[i,k] and replace !

Comment: Thanks for accepting my answer. I think that you should have a go at solving these problems yourself based on my answer and if you get stuck, ask a new question. You can use `sub` or `gsub` to perform substitutions and `==` to test whether the strings are equal. Good luck.

Comment: I will try to do for ! and comparation.  If your code able to extend to handle 3 input files, please update it.  Thanks.